# Quartz.Net en C# donet core. Inyeccion de dependencias. Como acceder al dbcontext?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cronjobs

Buen dia,

Tengo un proyecto en C# Asp.net-core 2.1, en el cual estoy incluyendo el uso de la libreria Quartz.Net para enviar unos correos electronicos mediante una tarea programada.

El lio que tengo es al tratar de leer la informacion desde el dbcontext ya que esto viene por inyeccion de dependencias, aun no he logrado acceder a este.

La aplicación esta divida en capas, una capa es un Api web services, en la cual inicio el Programador de Quartz, esto lo hago en el StartUp con la siguiente linea en el Configure:

```
Scheduler.Start();
```

Este llamado inicia el programador que esta asi:

```
public class Scheduler
{
    private readonly static Lazy<Scheduler> _instance = new Lazy<Scheduler>(() => new Scheduler());
    private static IScheduler scheduler;

    public static Scheduler Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return _instance.Value;
        }
    }

    public static async void Start()
    {
        scheduler = await StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
        await scheduler.Start();

        InicializarMonitoreo();

    }


    private static void InicializarMonitoreo()
    {
        EnviarCorreos();
    }

    public static void EnviarCorreos()
    {
        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<JobCorreoAdministradores>().WithIdentity("myJob", "myGroup").Build();

        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.CronSchedule("0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *"))
            .Build();

        Scheduler.AddJob(job, trigger);
    }


    public static void AddJob(IJobDetail job, ITrigger trigger)
    {
        scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
    }
}
```

Al iniciar el programador, que esta configurado para que corra cada minuto, llama el siguiente trabajo:

```
public class JobCorreoAdministradores: IJob
{
    public Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        List<string> emails = new List<string>();

        emails.Add("correo1@dominio.com");
        emails.Add("correo2@dominio.com");


        string asunto = "correo de prueba";
        string mensaje = "Hola este correo es de prueba para envio programado";

        EmailSender _emailSender = new EmailSender();
        _emailSender.SendMultipleRecipientsEmailAsync(emails, asunto, mensaje);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Al iniciar la tarea de esta manera, el job se ejecuta y envia los correos sin inconveniente alguno, es decir que asi funciona la tarea programada bien.

Ahora, el problema es que la lista de remitentes debe leerse desde una base de datos, pera lo que se requiere acceso al dbcontext, pero aun no logro obtener acceso a este, requiero algo como esto:

```
public class CorreoObjetosGeograficosAdministradores : IJob
{
    public Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        List<string> emails = new List<string>();

        var usuarios = dbcontext.Tabla.where(usuario => usuario.usuariomodificacion != null).select(usuarios => usuarios.email).ToList();

        foreach (var item in usuarios)
        {
            emails.Add(item);
        }

        string asunto = "correo de prueba";
        string mensaje = "Hola este correo es de prueba para envio programado";

        EmailSender _emailSender = new EmailSender(UrlAplicaciones.CORREO_HOST, UrlAplicaciones.CORREO_PORT, UrlAplicaciones.CORREO_ENABLE_SSL, UrlAplicaciones.CORREO_USER_NAME, UrlAplicaciones.CORREO_PASSWORD);
        _emailSender.SendMultipleRecipientsEmailAsync(emails, asunto, mensaje);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucioné mi problema de la siguiente manera, lo publico por si alguien lo necesita:

Después de indagar y probar muchas alternativas, en la documentación de Quartz encontré la interfaz IJobFactory y la implemente asi:

```
public class MyJobFactory : IJobFactory
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public MyJobFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        return (IJob)this._serviceProvider.GetService(bundle.JobDetail.JobType);       
    }

    public void ReturnJob(IJob job)
    {
        var disposable = job as IDisposable;
        disposable?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

En mi programador solo cambie el metodo Start por el siguiente, para que use una instancia de mi JobFactory creado, de igual manera publico todo mi programador:

```
public class Scheduler
{
    private readonly static Lazy<Scheduler> _instance = new Lazy<Scheduler>(() => new Scheduler());
    private static IScheduler scheduler;

    public static Scheduler Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return _instance.Value;
        }
    }

    public static async void Start(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            scheduler = await StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
            scheduler.JobFactory = new JobFactory(serviceProvider);
            await scheduler.Start();

            InicializarMonitoreo();

        }


    private static void InicializarMonitoreo()
    {
        EnviarCorreos();
    }

    public static void EnviarCorreos()
    {
        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<JobCorreoAdministradores>().WithIdentity("myJob", "myGroup").Build();

        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.CronSchedule("0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *"))
            .Build();

        Scheduler.AddJob(job, trigger);
    }


    public static void AddJob(IJobDetail job, ITrigger trigger)
    {
        scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
    }
}
```

Y finalmente en mi Starup:

1. Retiré del Configure la linea de codigo:

   Scheduler.Start();
2. En el ConfigureServices adicione los siguientes servicios (uno por cada job que necesite iniciar con inyeccion de dependencias) y llamo el nuevo metodo Start de mi Programador:

   services.AddScoped();
   services.AddScoped();

   var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

   Scheduler.Start(serviceProvider);

Y ya, en este momento tengo acceso a todos los datos inyectados en la aplicación, y puedo usar mi dbcontext con total normalidad tal y como lo necesitaba.

Espero les pueda ayudar.